# Google Spreadsheet Conditional Formatting with another Cell Value from Queries

Tags: google-sheets

[image: Actual view]

So I have this formula:

=if(D7>=D5,"PROFIT", IF(D7<=D6,"LOSS", "ACTIVE"))

and as you can see in the picture the value of D7 is not >=D5 and not <=D6 but the formula in D9 keeps giving me value LOSS which is not true. I was expecting to give value "ACTIVE".

Data in D6 and D5 are parsed with the query. Data in D7 is parsed with importxml.

Could you help me with this? Thank you

Comment: you can't see row numbers in your picture, but I assume D5 is 109.279?  If so, D7 (109) is less than D6(110.05) so it looks correct that it give the value of LOSS.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. No Chris active cells are those with frames. D5=110.05 / D6=109 / D7=109.34

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with my query. I don't know why but this part of the query "order by A desc LIMIT 10", 1" broke my formula. I removed this part and left just "=query(App!A1:K, "select B"" and it works perfectly. If somebody could help explain why that addition influenced my formula it will help a lot.

Comment: We can't explain what your query change since we don't know what you query does